# Error Handling in vb 2015 click event

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I am just learning vb 2015. I have developed a windows application to give lookup capability to an Access database by ID, Name, Company and Phone #. The user selects the type of lookup via a radio button. I then bring up a second form that asks for the user input in a textbox and displays a datagridview of the matching rows. When the user presses the button to accept the input the click event does extensive validation of the input and shows a message box if the input is invalid. At that point I want to clear the textbox and give it focus so the user can reenter the ID, phone #, etc. I have googled and tried an number if options with no joy. If I set the .clear and .focus in the click event and then return the focus is not in the textbox. The user can click into the text box and enter a new request but it seems more elegant to put the focus back in the textbox.

Where does the control return to after a click event? Is there a standard way of handling this in vb.net?

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: yes please post the click event code as the order of calls could be an issue.

Comment: I believe I found a solution. After I display the error message in the click code for the button to process the entryI simply did a Return. I created a validating event as follows:
'
Private Sub txtCustomerSelect_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles txtCustomerSelect.Validating
        e.Cancel = True
        txtCustomerSelect.Text = ""
End Sub'
The textbox is cleared and the focus is correct. If you want the invalid entry to still be visable just leave off the txtCustomerSelect.Text = "". I'm not sure if this is considered good form in a vb program but it works.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you are throwing an exception during your validation code.

Try putting any risky operations in a Try...Catch block, and do any necessary operations in the Finally area. This will also make sure that clearing, and re-focusing is the last thing you do.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        ' Validation code
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Handle exception
    Finally
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End Try
End Sub
```